# Issue with Sitefinity 7.3 on azure webrole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, telerik, azure-web-roles, sitefinity

I am migrating a sitefinity application onto an azure web role. The database is already migrated to sql azure. And with that connectionstring in DataConfig.config the application runs fine in my local machine. But once I add a cloud project and (made the necessary changes mentioned in telerik documentation - azure assemblies redirection,dataconfig change,app.dll.config file , internal endpoint, local storage) and set this application as a web role it does not work. When I run the cloud project in azure emulator locally or deploy as a cloud service  I get the following error.

> Enum conversion failed as the property/field is not nullable and no
>   value has been read from the database. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Enum conversion
>   failed as the property/field is not nullable and no value has been
>   read from the database.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Enum conversion failed as the
>   property/field is not nullable and no value has been read from the
>   database.]    OpenAccessRuntime.Data.EnumConverter.Read(DataHolder&
>   holder) +470
>   OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalGenericState.copyPass1Fields(ResultSet
>   rs, FetchGroupField[] fetchGroups, Int32 firstCol) +346
>
> [DataStoreException: Error reading field
>   Telerik.Sitefinity.Forms.Model.FormDraft.k__BackingField
>   from ResultSet: System.InvalidOperationException: Enum conversion
>   failed as the property/field is not nullable and no value has been
>   read from the database.    at
>   OpenAccessRuntime.Data.EnumConverter.Read(DataHolder& holder)    at
>   OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalGenericState.copyPass1Fields(ResultSet
>   rs, FetchGroupField[] fetchGroups, Int32 firstCol)
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Enum conversion failed as the
>   property/field is not nullable and no value has been read from the
>   database.    at OpenAccessRuntime.Data.EnumConverter.Read(DataHolder&
>   holder)    at
>   OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalGenericState.copyPass1Fields(ResultSet
>   rs, FetchGroupField[] fetchGroups, Int32 firstCol)]
>   DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_OpenAccessFormsProvider_f4f053b2c49247a8908c30d75bf02970.GetForm(Guid formId) +413
>   Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Forms.Web.UI.FormsControl.get_FormData()
>   +759    Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Forms.Web.UI.FormsControl.ProcessFormInitialization()
>   +21    Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Forms.Web.UI.FormsControl.InitializeControls(GenericContainer
>   container) +55
>   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.SimpleView.CreateChildControls() +88
>   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +60
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4297

I checked the telerik forum as well and found only 2 posts with this error but the solutions suggested did not work.

any solutions to resolve this issue will be helpful.

Comment: Can you try unpublishing any Forms you may have and see if that helps.

Comment: I am not sure about it as I don't know much about Sitefinity. my task is only for migrating it to azure.

Answer (score 0):

After adding assembly redirect for all the telerik dlls and other third party DLLs in web. Config and app.DLL.config I also ran 3 update scripts mentioned in sitefinity forum in the db. This fixed the issue and site came up.